# mysql create list of occuring values for column

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id | name | tag
------------------
1  | A    | blubb
2  | B    | blubb
3  | AB   | foo
4  | C    | bar
5  | AC   | blubb
6  | AC   | foo
```

Now i look for a Query that I can use to get a result like this:

```
foo, bar, blubb
```

It's not important whether the result is an array or list with commas as above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag SEPARATOR ',')
FROM table
```

Comment: Amazing, this works perfectly! I could not find any solution anywhere else. Thanks!